# Regex find this specific phone numbers from string Python

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to create a python script that **extract phone numbers from string using regex**. My actual code are able to retrieve 7/11 formats . Here are all the 11 numbers formats :

```
000-000-0000

000 000 0000

000.000.0000

(000)000-0000

(000)000 0000

(000)000.0000

(000) 000-0000

(000) 000 0000

(000) 000.0000

0000000000

(000)0000000
```

---

```
import re

Test = '000-000-0000 number 1 000 000 0000 number 2 000.000.0000 nbr3 (000)000-0000 nbr4 (000)000 0000 nbr5 (000)000.0000 nbr6 (000) 000-0000 nbr7 (000) 000 0000 nbr8 (000) 000.0000 nbr9 000-0000 nbr10 000 0000 nbr11 000.0000 nbr12 0000000 nbr13 0000000000 nbr14 (000)0000000 nbr'
phonetype1 = re.findall(r'(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4} | \(\d{3}\)\s *\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4} )', Test)
print(phonetype1)
print(len(phonetype1))
```

**The output is :**

```
['000-000-0000 ', '000 000 0000 ', '000.000.0000 ', ' (000) 000-0000 ', ' (000) 000 0000 ', ' (000) 000.0000 ', '0000000000 ']
7
```

**The formats (4/11) that i'm trying to retrieve are :**

```
(000)000-0000

(000)000 0000

(000)000.0000

(000)0000000
```

Comment: Remove spaces in the regex

Comment: @splash58 it's worked ! thank you

Comment: Just a general point: normalize your phone numbers before dealing with them. So you need to do the crazy magic on one and only one point.

Comment: @frlan yes you are right ! I'll start normalizing them first

Answer (score -1):

Use this pattern

```
\(\d{3}\)\d{3}([-.\s])?\d{4}
```

Try test cases [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com)

The selected matches

```
(000)000-0000

(000)000 0000

(000)000.0000

(000)0000000
```

Comment: It matches `(000)-000-0000`, and it shouldn't.

Comment: I'm sorry but your pattern doesn't match all the patterns he asked for !

Answer (score -1):

You could write the following.

```
import re

s = '000.000.0000 (000)000-0000 (000)000 0000 (000)000.0000 (000) 000-0000 (000) 000 0000 (000) 000.0000 0000000000 (000)0000000'

print re.findall(r'\(\d{3}\)\d{3}(?:-| |.|)\d{4}(?!\d)', s)
  #=> ['(000)000-0000', '(000)000 0000', '(000)000.0000', '(000)0000000']
```

[Demo](http://tpcg.io/3XD6w1Rf)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZyzMS/2/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\(\d{3}\)   match 3 digits in parentheses
\d{3}       match 3 digits
(?:-| |.|)  match '-', ' ', '.' or '' (empty string)
\d{4}       match 4 digits
(?!\d)      next char cannot be a digit (negative lookahead)
```

Answer (score -1):

This regex is working with all formats :

```py
^((\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}\ \d{3}\ \d{4})|(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4})|(\(\d{3}\)\ ?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4})|\d{10})$
```

or you can use it to get matches for phone numbers not beginning and ending in same line with this pattern :

```py
(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}\ \d{3}\ \d{4})|(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4})|(\(\d{3}\)\ ?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4})|\d{10}
```

You can check [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/HG8IFh/3/), this approach is very restrictive, and matches only the patterns you mentionned.